# Compare Elements in a double list and return a double List

Tags: python-3.x

I have this double list:

```
doubleL = [['123', 'user1', 'its.zip', '05-19-17'],
['123', 'user1', 'zippedtto.zip', '05-24-17'],
['123', 'user1', 'zippedtto.zip', '05-19-17'],
['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', '05-19-17'], 
['abcd', 'Letsee.zip', '05-22-17']]
```

[screenshot of my double list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK1fn.png)

I want to use python and check if the first two elements in each sub-list are the same and return a double list with their last element. For example in this case my output would be:

```
output = [ ['05-19-17', '05-24-17', '05-19-17' ], ['05-19-17'], ['05-22-17']]
```

What is the most pythonic way to get this output?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to make a dictionary, using the first two elements of a given sublist as the key (as a tuple), and a list containing the final element of the sublist as the value. Then get the values of the sublist.

Answer (score 0):

### Without defaultdict

```
tmp = {} # A dictionary

for x in doubleL: # Iterate over outer list
    # Set default as empty list if key not present
    # Else/And just append the last value
    tmp.setdefault((x[0], x[1]), []).append(x[-1]) 

print(list(tmp.values()) # Print values as list
```

### With defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

for x in doubleL: # Iterate over outer list
    # Just append the last value
    tmp[(x[0], x[1])].append(x[-1]) 

print(list(tmp.values()) # Print values as list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary but if you want to keep the order, you should use the module collections and OrderedDict as follow :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
D= OrderedDict()

for elem in doubleL:
    if (elem[0], elem[1]) in D.keys():
        D[(elem[0], elem[1])].append(elem[-1])
    else:
        D[(elem[0], elem[1])] = [elem[-1]]

print(list(D.values()))
```

Comment: What is dico on line 4 in the code above? (dico.keys())

Comment: my bad it's edited. I renamed dico to D from my IDE to the website but forgot this one :(

Answer (score 0):

A non-dictionary route would be to use `itertools.groupby`, and `sorted` to get all of the items in the correct order

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = []
for g, l in groupby(sorted(doubleL, key=lambda o: o[:2]), key=lambda o: o[:2]):
    groups.append([i[-1] for i in l])

print groups
>>> [['05-19-17', '05-24-17', '05-19-17'], ['05-19-17'], ['05-22-17']]
```